# Workaround for a load-balanced socket.io server without shared memory store

Tags: node.js, socket.io, load-balancing, shared-memory

I have a node.js / socket.io app that needs to run on a load balanced server. The server does not have sticky sessions enabled, so I cannot use something such as Redis to create a shared memory store for socket.io.

The socket.io website suggests doing something as per the attached illustration (taken from [here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/using-multiple-nodes/#why-is-sticky-session-required))

[image: illustration of a possible server setup]

My question is how could you go about actually implementing this?

Logically it makes sense - set up a connection between all the servers so they can pass any messages between themselves. Is there a node module already that can do this, or do I need to come up with my own logic? Would this require creating an additional socket connection between every server? And therefore knowing the internal IP of each server in order to connect to them all from every other server?

I know this isn't a recommended workflow and definitely isn't ideal. I feel like the solution may prove fairly overcomplicated. But if anyone has a suggestion of the best way to achieve this, that would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on what kind of app you wan't to build so if you can be more specific it would help. To answer your question "Is there a node module already that can do this, or do I need to come up with my own logic?" you should look into redis-adapter.

Answer (score 0):

This is not what you are asking but if you disable HTTP long-polling transport you don't need sticky sessions, per your link:

> if you disable the HTTP long-polling transport (which is a perfectly valid choice in 2021), you won't need sticky sessions:

This is what Socket.IO has to say about long polling, so keep this in mind:

> By default, the client establishes the connection with the HTTP long-polling transport. While WebSocket is clearly the best way to establish a bidirectional communication, experience has shown that it is not always possible to establish a WebSocket connection, due to corporate proxies, personal firewall, antivirus software...

Then you will be able to use the redis adapter to pass events between nodes.